# Javascript, form element not submitting

Tags: javascript, windows, asp-classic, salesforce

I have a JS file, that contains a couple of functions that allow me to send details off from a 'contact us' form to Salesforce.

When executing the sendToSalesForce() function from the JS console in the browser, everything works great, I get a debug email back to my address.

Now when executing the function when I click the submit button on the page, the sendToSalesForce() function is executing (iv'e stepped through the whole thing) although I don't get any debug emails back, so therefore, the form is not submitting.

When clicking the submit button, the JS that executes is something like:

```
 var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8";  


 for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                var element = document.createElement("input");  
                element.name=elements[i].name;
                element.value=elements[i].value;
                element.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                form.appendChild(element); 
                alert(element.value);
            }; 

document.body.appendChild(form); 
form.submit();
```

At the top of the contact-us form (ASP page):

```
<%
If Request.Form("submitform") = "1" Then 
Call ProcessForm
 Else
%>
<%=Content.Item("A")%>
<%  
Call DisplayForm
End If
%>
```

Although by the time it posts back to the asp page, I would have expected it to  have submitted by form element created by my Javascript?? Is there something I am missing...

Hope theres enough information here...

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Why are you using a form for this? Why not just send a POST XmlHttpRequest? ~ http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: Because I can't send a cross origin POST request...

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I thought Salesforce allowed that. Looks like they have their own AJAX API for sending POSTS http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/apex_ajax.pdf

Comment: Where is the function `sendToSalesForce` defined? Can't see it anywhere in your code, nor how you call it.

Comment: Hi Shadow, the function is in an external JS file, I have tried calling it in the onclick of the submit button, and also before submit on the first form. Like I said, I know the code is running as it hits the breakpoints and steps through all the code.

I have now done it server side, instead of the JS way, but it is still one of those nagging problems I would like to know why it is happening. I believe it could be something to do with the browser not liking you submitting more than one form?